# Change datatype in creating table when importing csv files to MySQL - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537093/add-backticks-in-creating-table-to-mysql-with-csv-file-php), I asked how to create table using backticks for my fields. Now our team decided to have  computations to some of our .csv files when importing it to mysql. However, our default datatype is **VARCHAR(500)**. Our table has an **Amount** column and we like that datatype to be INT. Can you give us hints on how to do it? Thank you.

Here's my code:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($data); $i++) {
    $f = strtolower(trim($data[$i]));
    if ($f) {
        // normalize the field name, strip to 20 chars if too long
        $f = substr(preg_replace ('/[^0-9a-z]/', '_', $f), 0, 100);
        $field_count++;
        $fields[] = $f.' VARCHAR(500)';
    }
}

$sqlcreate = "CREATE TABLE $table (" . implode(', ', $fields)  . ')';
echo $sqlcreate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use a different column type based on the name of the column, you could use either an if/then or switch/case statement:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($data); $i++) {
    $f = strtolower(trim($data[$i]));
    if ($f) {
        // normalize the field name, strip to 20 chars if too long
        $f = substr(preg_replace ('/[^0-9a-z]/', '_', $f), 0, 100);
        $field_count++;
        if($f == 'Amount') {
            $fields[] = $f.' INT(10)';
        } else {
            $fields[] = $f.' VARCHAR(500)';
        }
    }
}

$sqlcreate = "CREATE TABLE $table (" . implode(', ', $fields)  . ')';


echo $sqlcreate;
```

Comment: SORRY SCRATCH THAT!!!  
I was missing another equal sign there in  my code...  
$f == 'Amount' 
It worked :)

Comment: Thanks it working fine with our computations as well :)